# Proving a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a an arbitrary quadrilateral. Construct equilateral triangles on the edges pointing
inward and outward alternately. Let $\triangle ABP,\triangle BCS, \triangle CDR \;\text{and} \;\triangle 
 ADQ$ be these equilateral triangle. Show that $PQRS$ is a parallelogram.

[image: Magn Diagram]

I don't know what to do here. My guess is i should use the product of rotations here.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ParaFromTri.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you need to show $4$ pairs of congruent triangles, so that each side of $PQRS$ corresponds to a diagonal of $ABCD$.

For example, $\triangle PAQ \cong \triangle BAD$, and indeed, by intuition, they are congruent by rotation (however you need to show them vigorously, a better diagram might help)

Finally use the fact that a quadrilateral with equal opposite sides must be a parallelogram to draw the conclusion.